# Mapstruct dúvida

Tags: java, spring-boot

Eu fiz uma crud pra cadastrar um hospital, e comecei com o método save para salvar no banco de dados um hospital. Porem quando utilizei o mapstruct para converter o json para um dto e da erro 400 dizendo que o os valores passados no json sao nulos.

Esse é o service

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class HospitalService {

    private HospitalRepository hospitalRepository;

    public Hospital save(RequestDto requestDto) {
        return hospitalRepository.save(HospitalMapper.INSTANCE.dtoToHospital(requestDto));
    }
}
```

Esse daqui é o mapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public abstract class HospitalMapper {

    public static final HospitalMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(HospitalMapper.class);

    public abstract Hospital dtoToHospital(RequestDto requestDto);
}
```

Esse é o controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/hospital")
public class HospitalController {

    private HospitalService hospitalService;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Hospital> saveHospital(@RequestBody @Valid RequestDto requestDto) {
        Hospital save = hospitalService.save(requestDto);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(save);
    }

}
```

Esse é o erro:

```
"timestamp": "2021-12-20T16:13:20.533+00:00",
"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"trace": "org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed for argument [0] in public  
org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<br.com.crud.tascom.model.Hospital> 
br.com.crud.tascom.controller.HospitalController.saveHospital(br.com.crud.tascom.controller.hospitalDto.RequestDto)
with 4 errors: [Field error in object 'requestDto' on field 'telefone': 
rejected value [null]; codes [NotNull.requestDto.telefone,NotNull.telefone,NotNull]; arguments 
[org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes 
[requestDto.telefone,telefone]; arguments []; default message [telefone]]; 
default message [must not be null]] [Field error in object 'requestDto' on 
field 'nome': rejected value [null]; codes [NotEmpty.requestDto.nome,NotEmpty.nome,NotEmpty]; arguments 
[org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes 
[requestDto.nome,nome]; arguments []; default message [nome]]; default 
message [must not be empty]] [Field error in object 'requestDto' on field 
'nome': rejected value [null]; codes [NotNull.requestDto.nome,NotNull.nome,NotNull]; arguments 
[org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes 
[requestDto.nome,nome]; arguments []; default message [nome]]; default 
message [must not be null]] [Field error in object 'requestDto' on field 
'telefone': rejected value [null]; codes 
[NotEmpty.requestDto.telefone,NotEmpty.telefone,NotEmpty]; arguments 
[org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes 
[requestDto.telefone,telefone]; arguments []; default message [telefone]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma possível solução é...

1. Crie um bean de ModelMapper a ser injetado. Exclua HospitalMapper.

```java
@Configuration
public class MapperConfig {

    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        return new ModelMapper();
    }
}
```

2. Modifique o `HospitalService` para:

```java
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class HospitalService {

    private final HospitalRepository hospitalRepository;
    private final ModelMapper mapper;

    public Hospital save(RequestDto requestDto) {
        return hospitalRepository.save(mapper.map(requestDto, Hospital.class));
    }
}
```

Dessa forma o ModelMapper disponível (esse bean declarado no passo 1) é injetado no HospitalService.

Lembrando:

- `@RequiredArgsConstructor` que foi adicionado gera um construtor com os parâmetros que são final como argumentos e com isso o Spring injeta nesse construtor o Mapper.
- outro ponto é que na criação desse mapper, você poderia até mudar a configuração dele se for o caso.
- outra coisa: eu não deixaria como argumento do método `save` do `HospitalService` um objeto do tipo `RequestDto`. Eu faria o mapper converter antes de mandar pra ele, no controller mesmo. Porque não faz sentido uma classe de alto nível (Service) depender de uma classe de baixo nível (api). O motivo disso é que se você criar uma outra interface que conecta ao seu sistema, o `service` estaria isolado e com um argumento do modelo Hospital e não com um RequestDto.